# How do you say "of good stock" vs. "of weak stock" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, nuances, phrases

I'm trying to translate into Japanese for an academic paper a quote from a 19th century eugenics book into Japanese. It contains the phrase "Those with lower ideals will continue to restrict their families, and, with **the weaker and unsound stocks**, will weed themselves out of the race."

I found 虚弱体質である、身体が虚弱である、身体が弱い、病身である for "have a weak constitution"; 体質が健全だ、体格がいい for "have a good constitution"; and よいしつけ、正しい作法、育ちの良い for "of good breeding".

However, none of these include the English nuance about animals that are in the words "stock" (as in "livestock") or "breeding," which I think should come across in a book written by misled eugenicists who considered some human families to be quality stock and others to be low quality stock. I'm looking for **a word in Japanese that could be used to refer to humans but is largely associated with the idea of animals as a lower species**. To refer to the people who the authors thought should die off as 方、者、or 人 seems like the demeaning nuance would be lost.

My translation so far is as follows, with the spots for "stock" marked by blanks:

> "[T]he realization of the power of limiting the birth-rate . . . [means] [t]hose who, sound in body and mind, possess a high moral tone and a clear appreciation of their social responsibilities . . . will produce many offspring.  Those with lower ideals will continue to restrict their families, and, with the weaker and unsound stocks, will weed themselves out of the race."
>
> 「出生率を制限するの力が実現される意味は心身ともに健全である、倫理的に高い基準を示す、社会的責任をはっきりと理解するは多くの子孫を生み出すことになる。理想が弱く者は彼らの家族を制限続けると、身体が虚弱である____と精神障害を抱えている____とともに、自分自身が人類から一掃する」

(There are probably various grammatical errors in the translation at this point [1st draft] so I apologize for that [any tips on improving it as a whole would be gladly welcome as well].)

Comment: @eltonjohn Thank you so much, this is extremely helpful. Would you like to make it an answer? I think "restrict" means to limit the number of people in their families (i.e. choose to have less children or no children) and "the race" means "the human race." Can 競争 be used in the context of survival of the fittest within the human race as a competition?

Comment: I made it an answer and I will withdraw the original comment. <Can 競争 be used in the context of survival of the fittest within the human race as a competition?> I think so. We use "生存競争", "適者生存" and "自然選択/淘汰" in that context.

Comment: I think "restrict" means to limit the number of people in their families (i.e. choose to have less children or no children) >>> 「理想の低い者は家族(の数)を制限し続け」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that context I would use "家{か}系{けい}" or "系{けい}統{とう}" meaning "lineage" and "descent" respectively.

And I wonder if the following helps :

> 「出生率を制限する力が実現する」とは、心身ともに健全で、倫理的に高い基準を持ち、社会的責任を明確に理解した人々が多くの子孫を生み出し、基準値‌​が低い人々は、‌​その家族の(構成員)数を減らし、身体が虚弱で精神障害を抱えている系統は、競争から脱落する、という意味である

Of course the above is one of many possibilities.